# BlockFrost IPFS error

Tags: blockfrost, ipfs

I can't upload an image to IPFS through
[ipfs.blockfrost.io/api/v0/ipfs/add](https://ipfs.blockfrost.io/api/v0/ipfs/add)
from browser. I am trying to upload image dircetly from frontend of my application (browser extension). I get this response:

```
{
"statusCode": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'\n    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'\n    --- property 'socket' closes the circle"
}
```

When I try to do the same request from node.js server everything is fine. I use the same fetch call on both front and back:

```js
let add = await fetch('https://ipfs.blockfrost.io/api/v0/ipfs/add', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'project_id': 'ipfsP0t7F3zOIIl6Op5fpM3c2q3CBYyYa7em'
},
body: form
});
```

It seems like there is a problem on blockfrost's server side with parsing additional headers that browser adds.
Or is this behaviour intentional and I shouldn't be able to send requests from frontend? Then the error seems uninformative.

Has anybody faced a similar problem?

Comment: What is your `Content-Type` header?